# Legend size/marker in relplot seaborn

Tags: python, legend, scatter-plot

I've been looking in SO for increasing legend/hue size in relplot.

```
plt.rcParams["axes.labelsize"] = 20
g = sns.relplot(x='Time(days)', y='Duration Total (s)', hue='Outcome', data=t1,height=15, aspect=1, s=50);
plt.suptitle("a_10",fontsize=25, fontweight='bold')
```

I can't seem to wrap my heads around it. There're so many mixed references, it's all a bit confusing.

Comment: Do you want to increase the text size or the marker size (or both)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've spent some time digging through this, an yes, you're right to say it's confusing.

I will also assume you are talking about text size, and not marker size.

## Ways that work

There are two main ways I would suggest you to increase the legend size (retrieved from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328003/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-using-seaborn-facetgrid)):

- Scaling up the font globally using `sns.set()`. For example:

```
sns.set(font_scale=1.5)
# plotting code here...
```

- Scaling up the font locally using `sns.plotting_context()`. For example:

```
with sns.plotting_context("notebook", font_scale=1.5):
    # plotting code here...
```

The problem with both approaches is that **they also increase the size of other elements**. So, for example, axis labels will grow alongside the legend:

[image]
[image]

## Way that doesn't work

In the mentioned SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53022816/7835318), there's also an answer that addresses directly modifying the legend. It uses the private property `_legend` of the `FacetGrid` and increase the text size directly:

```
g = sns.relplot(x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', hue='species', data=iris)
plt.setp(g._legend.get_texts(), fontsize=16)
```

This method, however, severely messes up with the formatting. From a quick glance, I think it happens because `FacetGrid` calculates its size using the legend dimensions. So, altering the legend afterwards messes things up.

[image]

## What to do?

From my research, it looks like there's no simple way to do what you want. You can submit an issue to the [seaborn repository](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/) and maybe they will fix it (you can give a reference to your question). More hopefully, there *is* a way to do it and they will simply point out how.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 5):

If anyone still stumbles across this post, here is a solution that worked for me:

[How to set legend marker size and alpha?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48694620/how-to-set-legend-marker-size-and-alpha)

The required code being:

```
for lh in g._legend.legendHandles: 
    lh.set_alpha(1)
    lh._sizes = [50]
```

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't have more upvotes. It works perfectly