# Seaborn plot adjusting "plotting_context" not working as expected for legend marker size

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to adjust the legend markers in a Seaborn jointplot. Based on the answer by "MaozGelbart" on [this Github issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1751), I expected `rcParams` to work for this. The configurations are in the matplotib documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html), and I think `legend.markerscale` is the parameter I am interested in.

How can I change the legend marker scale? This code below does not work. However, it does work for the `legend.fontsize` parameter.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

d = {
    'x': [3,2,5,1,1,0],
    'y': [1,1,2,3,0,2],
    'cat': ['a','a','a','b','b','b']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
with sns.plotting_context(rc={"legend.fontsize": 'x-small', "legend.markerscale": 0.5}):
    g = sns.jointplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='cat')
```

[image]

There is a similar [Stack Overflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56013313/legend-size-marker-in-relplot-seaborn) but it looks like there is no clear answer. Besides, setting `rcParams` should work, in theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Setting a fixed size for points in legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706125/setting-a-fixed-size-for-points-in-legend), calling `.set_sizes([...])` on the legend handles should work.

For a `jointplot()` this would be called as:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'x': [3, 2, 5, 1, 1, 0],
     'y': [1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2],
     'cat': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
with sns.plotting_context(rc={"legend.fontsize": 'x-large'}):
    g = sns.jointplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='cat')
for h in g.ax_joint.get_legend().legendHandles:
    h.set_sizes([10])
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: thanks, this works. any idea why `rcParams` does not work? is it a bug?

Comment: is there a Pythonic way to do `for h in g...` as a one-liner? Doing `test = [h for h in g.ax_joint.get_legend().legendHandles]` gets the handles into a list, but I am not sure how to apply the `set_sizes`

Comment: `[h.set_sizes(..) for h in g.ax_joint.get_legend().legendHandles]` would work, but I don't think that is the recommended Pythonic way.  The `"legend.markerscale"` probably is meant for markers created with a line plot, not a scatter plot.  Or maybe it is just some functionality that has changed.