# Increase marker size in seaborn pairplot legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to increase the size of the markers in a seaborn pairplot **legend**.
The plot without any attempted scaling:

[image]

df:

```
a   b   c
0   1   0   0
1   0   1   0
2   0   0   1
3   1   0   0
```

```
se = pd.Series(list('abca'))
df = pd.get_dummies(se)
display(df)
ax=sns.pairplot(df,vars=['a','b','c'], hue='c',palette=sns.color_palette(sns.hls_palette(8, l=.4, s=.8), len(np.unique(df['a']))))
ax.fig.legend(markerscale=2)
```

The code above gives the following result, which is obviously not correct.
[image]

I also tried with adding ,plot_kws={'s':50}, but that scaled both the points in the legend AND the points inside the plot, which I do not want.

```
ax=sns.pairplot(df,vars=['a','b','c'], hue='c',palette=sns.color_palette(sns.hls_palette(8, l=.4, s=.8), len(np.unique(df['a']))),plot_kws={'s':50})
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try adding "plot_kws=3" parameter in the sns.pairplot function?

Comment: Try: `,plot_kws={'s':50}` as an additional keyword argument to `sns.pairplot()`

Comment: That changes the size of the internal points as well. I only want to change the size of the legend markers. @mechanical_meat

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48694620/how-to-set-legend-marker-size-and-alpha is the solution for anyone wandering.

Comment: First, this question is not a duplicate as indicated above, as it is about the markers, and second, the lmplot version does not work for pairplot. Or the API has changed.